# How to generate new variable (column) based on a specific given column containing cycles of numbers from 0 to n, where n is a positive integer

Tags: python, excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

The dataset contains data about COVID-19 patients. It is in both EXCEL and CSV file formats, and contains **several variables** and over **7 thousand records (rows)** which has made the problem extremely harder and very time consuming to solve manually. Below are the 4 most important variables (columns) needed in solving the problem; 1: `id` for identifying each record (row), 2: `day_at_hosp` for each day a patient remained admitted at the hospital, 3: `sex` of patient, 4: `death` for whether the patient eventually died or survived.
I want to create a new variable `total_days_at_hosp` which should contain a total of days a patient remained admitted at hospital.

```
Old Table:
 _______________________________________
|   id  | day_at_hosp |  sex   | death  |
|_______|_____________|________|________|
|   1   |     0       |  male  |   no   |
|   2   |     1       |        |        |
|   3   |     2       |        |        |
|   4   |     0       | female |   no   |
|   5   |     1       |        |        |
|   6   |     0       |  male  |   no   |
|   7   |     0       | female |   no   |
|   8   |     0       |  male  |   no   |
|   9   |     1       |        |        |
|  10   |     2       |        |        |
|  11   |     3       |        |        |
|  12   |     4       |        |        |
| ...   |    ...      |   ...  |  ...   |
| 7882  |     0       | female |   no   |
| 7883  |     1       |        |        |
|_______|_____________|________|________|

New Table:
I want to convert table above into table below:
 ____________________________________________
|   id  |total_days_at_hosp|  sex   | death  |
|_______|__________________|________|________|
|   1   |        3         |  male  |   no   |
|   4   |        2         |  male  |   yes  |
|   6   |        1         |  male  |   yes  |
|   7   |        1         | female |   no   |
|   8   |        5         |  male  |   no   |
| ...   |       ...        |   ...  |  ...   |
| 2565  |        2         | female |   no   |
|_______|__________________|________|________|
```

NOTE: the `id` column is for every record entered, and multiple records were entered for each patient depending on how long a patient remained admitted at the hospital. The `day_at_hosp` variable contains days: 0=initial day at hospital, 1=second day at hospital, ... , n=nth last day at hospital.
The record (row) where the variable (column) `day_at_hosp` is **0** corresponds to all entries in other columns, if the record (row) for `day_at_hosp` is **not 0*, say 1,2,3, ...,5 then it belongs to the patient right above, and all the corresponding variables (columns) are left blank.
However the dataset I need should look like the table below.
It should include a new variable (column) called `total_days_at_hosp` generated from the variable (column) `day_at_hosp`. The new variable (column) `total_days_at_hosp` is more useful in statistical tests to be conducted and will replace variable (column) `day_at_hosp`, so that all blank rows can be deleted.
To move from old table to new table the needed program should do the following:

```
day_at_hosp ===> total_days_at_hosp
    0                                 
    1        --->        3               
    2
-------------------------------------                              
    0        --->        2           
    1                              
-------------------------------------
    0        --->        1          
-------------------------------------
    0        --->        1
-------------------------------------
    0                                  
    1                                  
    2        --->        5                
    3
    4                                  
-------------------------------------
   ...                                 
------------------------------------- 
    0         --->       2                                              
    1
-------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So for each ID get the max plus 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another formula option without dummy value placed at end of the Old/New Table.

1] Create New Table by >>

- Copy and paste all Old Table data to a unused area
- Click "Autofilter"
- In "days_at_hospital" column select =0 value
- Copy and paste filter of admissions to New Table column F
- Delete all 0s in rows of Column G

Then,

2] In `G2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(F2="","",IF(F3="",MATCH(9^9,A:A)+1,MATCH(F3,A:A,0))-MATCH(F2,A:A,0))
```

Remark : If your "ID Column" is Text value, formula changed to :

```
=IF(F2="","",IF(F3="",MATCH("zzz",A:A)+1,MATCH(F3,A:A,0))-MATCH(F2,A:A,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent that your data are sorted by patient, and that your desired table will be much 'shorter' - accordingly the starting point for this answer is to apply an `AutoFilter` to your original data, setting the filter criterion to be `days_at_hospital = 0`, and then copy this filter of admissions to column F:
[image]
after deleting the old column G data, the formula below can then be entered in cell `G2` and copied down

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)-1)+1
```

to keep the formula simple the *same* dummy maximum value should be entered at both the end of the old *and* new tables.